# Switching branches in git without git checkout

Tags: git, branch

How do I switch between two branches without a *git checkout*? I will use kmod_git package as an illustration. After I cloned the kmod_git package, *git branch* shows it is on a ***master** branch. I go ahead to successfully cross compile the master branch. Now, I do a  *make clean* and do a *git checkout -b v12*. *git branch* now shows kmod_git has **master** and ***v12** branches. And, I have also successfully cross compiled the v12 branch. With v12 as the current working branch, is it possible to switch to between the two branches without using a *git checkout*? Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with `git checkout`?!

Answer (score 0):

Switching to a branch is what `git checkout` does, so no, you can't switch to a branch without `git checkout`.